# data.table - join NA keys

Tags: r, data.table

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select NA in a data.table in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646172/select-na-in-a-data-table-in-r)

just wondering if this is an intended feature or a bug in data.table?

```
a = data.frame(a=c(NA,1),aa=c(0,11))
b = data.frame(a=c(1),bb=c(11))
merge(a,b,all.x=T,by="a")
   a aa bb
1  1 11 11
2 NA  0 NA

a = data.table(a=c(NA,1),aa=c(0,11))
b = data.table(a=c(1),bb=c(11))
merge(a,b,all.x=T,by="a")
    a aa bb
1: NA  0 11
2:  1 11 11
```

same again this way

```
setkey(b,a)
b[a]
    a bb aa
1: NA 11  0
2:  1 11 11
```

I'd really expect the behaviour you get with data.frame this case.

thansk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See  [FR#1043 Allow or disallow NA in keys?.](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1043&group_id=240&atid=978).

It is a known issue, `NA` values are allowed, but you can't join with them.

See the duplicate question and answer [Select NA in a data.table in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646172/select-na-in-a-data-table-in-r) for a more detailed description

Comment: thanks, but I still don't understand how it gets that value in the join that should be NA (ie bb column)? I think this way results in something very unexpected.