# Join data.table unexpected NA values

Tags: r, data.table

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [data.table - join NA keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521843/data-table-join-na-keys)

I have already asked this question, but didn't get any good answers. If I join two data.tables which contain NA keys I get something unexpected.

```
a = data.table(a=c(NA,1,11,NA,NA),aa=c(0,11,333,3,5))
b = data.table(a=c(NA,1,33,2),bb=c(11,NA,100,3))
merge(a,b,by="a",all.x=T)
    a  aa bb
1: NA   0 NA
2: NA   3  3
3: NA   5  3
4:  1  11 NA
5: 11 333 NA
```

which should be identical to

```
merge(b,a,by="a",all.y=T)
    a bb  aa
1: NA 11   5
2: NA NA   0
3: NA NA   3
4:  1 NA  11
5: 11 NA 333
```

interestingly none of them are what you'd expect to get as an output.

Comment: Please don't repost questions. Use a [bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) to attract attention to the original. That being said, the answer I posted (to the original) and the link explains why it won't work.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that it doesn't work, I'm after understating what to expect as an output instead.

Comment: You can *expect* output that doesn't make sense. (Perhaps you could expect an error message)

Comment: The feature of joins/merges on NA/NaNs have been implemented in v1.8.11. Check out [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646172/select-na-in-a-data-table-in-r/20590133#20590133) for more info. Although your question on these two merges having the same output doesn't make sense.