# NA/NaN/Inf in data.table 1.9.2

Tags: r, data.table

After checking the new feature of data.table 1.9.2, I'm not quite clear about the new feature of manipulation of NA/NaN/Inf.

The news:

> NA, NaN, +Inf and -Inf are now considered distinct values, may be in keys, can be joined to and can be grouped. data.table defines: NA < NaN < -Inf

I don't know what does it mean by "can be joined to and can be grouped"

```
DT <- data.table(A=c(NA,NA,1:3), B=c("a",NA,letters[1:3]))
```

Now we have NAs in both column A and B,

But I'm lost a little how to proceed, and what the purpose of this new feature is. Could you provide an example to illustrate this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In previous versions of `data.table` `NA, NaN,Inf` values could exist in the key, but you could not `join` or use binary scan to select these rows in a consistent manner with other key values.

See 
[Select NA in a data.table in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646172/select-na-in-a-data-table-in-r) and [data.table subsetting by NaN doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237893/data-table-subsetting-by-nan-doesnt-work) for examples of SO questions that deal with these issues (and you can trace the history through the answers to Feature requests within the data.table project)

Now, in 1.9.2 (and above) such things will work.

```
# an example data set
DT <- data.table(A = c(NA,NaN,Inf,Inf,-Inf,NA,NaN,1,2,3), 
              B =letters[1:10], key = 'A')
# selection using binary search
DT[.(Inf)]
#     A B
# 1: Inf c
# 2: Inf d
DT[.(-Inf)]
#       A B
# 1: -Inf e
# note that you need to use the right kind of NA
DT[.(NA_real_)]
#     A B
# 1: NA a
# 2: NA f
DT[.(NaN)]
#      A B
# 1: NaN b
# 2: NaN g
# grouping works
DT[,.N,by=A]
#       A N
# 1:   NA 2
# 2:  NaN 2
# 3: -Inf 1
# 4:    1 1
# 5:    2 1
# 6:    3 1
# 7:  Inf 2
```

Comment: there's a minor question, is there a way to select "NaN" and "Inf" at the same time using .() method? Thanks!

Comment: @BigChao. Read the data.table help files. The same way you would select any other two values.